# wifislax unable to run commands and monitor mode

Tags: linux

Please tell that how to enable monitor mode in the wifislax4.10.1 as the following is coming when applying to make monitor mode.

[image: 22.png]

[image: snapshot1.png]

[image: 23.png]

[image: 24.png]

[image: 25.png]

[image: 26.png]

[image: 27.png]

Comment: please tell that why the software is not working according to the documentation and described commands?